# Variable stored in Session array becoming an object as opposed to an array of objects

Tags: php

I am storing some data in the Session variable. I want $_SESSION['hero'] to hold an array of objects. The syntax I am using below works fine on my local environment and on one of my hosting account. However, it fails to work on another hosting account I am testing out. On the second request to this script on the new hosting environment, the array of objects becomes just an object.

I thought the version of PHP I am using might be the problem. Upon examination, I see that I am using PHP 5.4.7 locally, and 5.2.17 on both of the hosted accounts. Since both hosted accounts are using PHP 5.2.17, it seems version of PHP isn't the issue.

Is there some setting in php.ini file that I'm not aware of that could be causing the code not to work in the one hosted account? Some other server setting? Problem with my code/understanding? Any advice is appreciated.

Here is images of the output I am getting when running this code on each of my hosting accounts.

Good output - http://imgur.com/Ed8MTkr,zm9WaeV#1

Bad output - http://imgur.com/Ed8MTkr,zm9WaeV#0

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$_SESSION['hero'][] = new Stdclass();
$heroIndex = count($_SESSION['hero']) - 1;
echo 'Last position in array: ' . $heroIndex;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION['hero']);
echo '</pre>';

$hero = $_SESSION['hero'][$heroIndex]; //Seems to be the trouble line

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION['hero']);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

**EDIT RESOLVED**

Thanks dirt, it was register_globals.

I tested it by setting register_globals to 'On' from 'Off' in the php.ini file on my local environment, and that reproduced the unexpected behavior that I was experiencing on the new hosting server.

I then added the following line to the .htaccess file on the hosted server (seemed the server wouldn't use my php.ini file).

`php_flag register_globals off`

It's nice to know the fix, now off to research this to better understand WHY it wasn't working. =)

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try usin it alike an array like

```
$_SESSION['hero']['heroIndex'] = count($_SESSION['hero']) - 1;

$hero = $_SESSION['hero']['heroIndex'];
```

Comment: No, it would be the value stored at that position just like a 2D array

Comment: I dont want the array at $_SESSION['hero'] to be indexed by the string 'heroIndex'. I want it to be indexed by ints.

Comment: Seems weird it would work on one server but not another. You check include paths/autoloaders? Where/when is StdClass getting loaded? Compare phpinfo() on each server and check register_globals